# if feature has 4 unique values ( number of products: 1 ,2,3,4 ) so should i treat that as categorical or discreate variable?

Tags: predictive-modeling, statistics, feature-selection, data-cleaning

I am using bank churn data (https://www.kaggle.com/kmalit/bank-customer-churn-prediction/data)

there is a column in data called  NumOfProducts that has 4 unique values so should I treat that as a categorical variable and make dummy variables or leave it as it is... please mention why should I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use it with its semantical meaning: the variable is numerical (of discrete type). As such, the ordering between such values has a specific meaning and a model could learn features as:
$$NumOfProducts \bowtie a,$$

where $\bowtie \, \in \{<,\le, =, \neq, \ge, >\}$ and $a \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Meanwhile, if you treat $NumOfProducts$ as nominal, categorical variable, then you lose the semantical ordering between values and, in such case, $\bowtie \, \in \{=,\neq\}$ only.